# Can anyone tell why I am getting such error?

Tags: node.js, ejs

[I am getting such error in my terminal. I can't understand why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUgas.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the code inside `app.js`? Otherwise it's impossible to say what causes the error...

Comment: const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo.  .";

const app = express;

app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");
});



app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and error message as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  A [mcve] would maximize your chance of getting help.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the following change

`const app = express;`  to `const app = express();`